# why IsBefore moment js gives me false when should be true

Tags: javascript, momentjs

My code is this:

```
const nowDate = moment(new Date()).format("DD/MM/YYYY");


let paraRepDate = '01/01/2021';
let  calcParaDate = '30/06/2021';

var x = moment(calcParaDate).isBefore(nowDate)
console.log(x) // false
```

How is it possible?

Comment: `moment(calcParaDate)` isn’t a valid Moment.js date object. `nowDate` isn’t a date object at all.

Comment: But its gives me a date.

Comment: Sorry if offtopic but just to let you know `moment.js` is considered "abandoned". They encourage you to switch to something like `dayjs` or similar (https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)

Answer (score 2):

Default format of momentjs is `MM/DD/YYYY`. In your solution you can see warning information in console:

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.

### Solution

You have to specify format `moment(date, format)`. Something like this:

```js
const format = 'DD/MM/YYYY';
const nowDate = moment();
const calcParaDate = '30/06/2021';
const isBefore = moment(calcParaDate, format).isBefore(nowDate)
console.log(isBefore);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment-with-locales.min.js" integrity="sha512-LGXaggshOkD/at6PFNcp2V2unf9LzFq6LE+sChH7ceMTDP0g2kn6Vxwgg7wkPP7AAtX+lmPqPdxB47A0Nz0cMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

---

Also you don't have to pass `new Date()` in `moment()` for current datetime.